# WPF or ASP.NET as WCF Client

Tags: asp.net, wpf, wcf, web-services

I am new to WCF and going through tutorials right now. I was wondering what are the benefits and disadvantages of using a WPF or an ASP.NET web application as a client for a service. I understand it will depend on the kind of service, but besides the common difference of one being a windows app and other a web application, what are the advantages of one over other.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# client app vs. web app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319088/c-sharp-client-app-vs-web-app)

Comment: Deployment with a web app is generally easier. You're only deploying one copy to the server instead of each user. Unless you're in a corporate environment where the browser choice is locked down, you may have to support N browser types for your users with a web app.

Comment: The WCF service is not aware if the client is WPF or ASP.NET.  The proper or best client is the proper or best client client.  Since ASP.NET is a more controlled environment there is not as much need for WCF.  A web app can hit a database and still have port 1433 closed.  Where letting a WPF app hit a database directly greatly increases the attack surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the choice of client technology does not depend at all on the kind of service you will be talking to. Both WPF/Winforms and a Web app will be perfectly capable to talk to a web service.

Instead, choice of client technology should purely be driven by requirements on the **client side**

Factors that you should consider when coosing one client technology over the other are:

- Know-How available to you (and your team)
- Deployment scearios: How do you get your app to the users, etc.
- Client environment: How many OSs do you need to support, how many different browsers would you have to support when doing a web app?
- Do you have occasionally connected scenarios, or do you need privileged access to client resources? - This would tip the scale somewhat towards a Rich client.

Even so, in many cases a web app appears to be a very valid option as you have access to a wealth of non-MS tech like Javascript Frameworks, CSS resources etc. etc.

On a personal note: Do not use WCF to define your web services - there are fantastic Open Source Frameworks, most notably [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) that will make you more productive and concentrate on what your service does and less on the mechanics and abstractions.